# egit and git unstaged files show different  status

Tags: git, git-svn, egit

i use git svn fetch svn repo,and do clone->branch->rebase->merge->dcommit step.with eclipse egit and cygwin client,do some days developing all is ok.

but one day ,after a merge/dcommit step,i found eclipse egit stage view status is different from git status in cygwin command line.when some files unstaged changes in eclipse,cygwin 'git status' show nothing changes;if commit with egit in elcipse,the cygwin command 'git status' show the  unstaged files changed that what just commited with egit.and if commit changes with cygiwn git client,egit show the same staged files changed.the problom files is always some files.

i've use blow method,but useless
git reset --hard.
reclone the svn repo .importing new cloned repo from svn to eclipse project,it show the file changed at start,and always those files.

anybody help!!

Comment: Same problem here. No solution found so far. I was guessing it could have something to do with the line endings...

Answer (score 2):

Total shot in the dark, but: do you have a symlink in one part of your repo, pointing to another part of it?  I have that problem, and it confuses eclipse (but does not confuse the command-line git).

[Eclipse, Egit and Symlinks or symbolic links - Is it possible to make a dirty eclipse plugin to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011873/eclipse-egit-and-symlinks-or-symbolic-links-is-it-possible-to-make-a-dirty-ec)