# Eclipse, Egit and Symlinks or symbolic links - Is it possible to make a dirty eclipse plugin to fix this?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

It's been years the problem exists because there isn't a portable way for eclipse or java to detect symlinks.

Now symlinks are very, very useful so regardless of the non portable reason, **would it be possible from an eclipse plugin to fix this and not have Egit consider symlinks and everything under it to be new files?**

Answer (score 5):

We plan to implement in JGit using Java 7 (though there is no concrete timeline yet, contributions welcome), see [1], there is also a draft for a JNI based native implementation [2].

[1] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354367
[2] https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/2125/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look as if this is going to happen any time soon, as this issue has apparently been around for ages. Unfortunately this a showstopper for me using egit. :-( And yes, I know, there's nothing to complain about in an open source project. I guess I should contribute myself...

Comment: Have you seen the issue discussed anywhere online, and if so could you post a link to it?